# How to get a list of all views in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

I would like to get a list of all views inside a main `Fragment`, so that I could iterate through them in a for loop. Maybe something like this:

```
for (View v : fragmentViews) {
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, fragment has method getView() :

> Get the root view for the fragment's layout (the one returned by
>   {@link #onCreateView}), if provided. @return The fragment's root view,
>   or null if it has no layout.

You can do this like:

```
    try {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) getView();
        int childViewCount = rootView.getChildCount();
        for (int i=0; i<childViewCount;i++){
            View workWithMe = rootView.getChildAt(i);
        }
    } catch (ClassCastException e){
        //Not a viewGroup here
    } catch (NullPointerException e){
        //Root view is null
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inflate your fragment the usual way in your `onCreateView`:-

`View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);`

To loop through views of your fragment:

```
ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) rootView;
int count = container.getChildCount();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    View v = container.getChildAt(i);
    // perform action on this view
}
```

Comment: Unsafe cast, rootView could be null